# Program stops working and it says zsh abort

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, zsh, abort

So here is my code

```
#include<math.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include"hw1.h"

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int num_choices, k; 
    char right_choices[20];
    
    do {
        printf("Enter number of choices:\n");
        scanf("%d", &num_choices);
    }
    while ((num_choices > 26) || (num_choices < 1));

    num_choices = num_choices - 1 + 'A';
    printf("Max choice:%c\n", (char)num_choices);

    printf("Enter answer key:\n");
        for( k=1; k < 20; k++)
        scanf(" %c", &right_choices[20]);


    return 0;
}
```

while compiling everything seems ok. While running the second scanf is supposed to run 20 times but everytime it stops at 19 and it says : "zsh abort"

I tried doing it 10 times to see if that was the problem but the same message appeared at the 9th time. It always stops at n-1.

The same code runs on linux perfectly.

Thank you very much!

i searched up the problem but i didnt find any usefull information

Comment: Your loop should be for (k = 0; k < 20; ++k). Also, you are overflowing your right_choices[] array by accessing at offset 20. Arrays in C start at index 0. Did you mean to use 'k' as your index instead of 20?

Comment: `&right_choices[20]` breaks the array. Also, you don't use `num_choices` except to report it.

Comment: I doubt it runs perfectly on Linux, either. :-)

Comment: Try pressing ctrl-d (or ctrl-z return in Windows) on the first prompt. :)

Comment: Are you perhaps running it on Mac? Linux would likely tell you `Segmentation fault` while windows would just say `Access violation exception`. Both of which mean one of the two things: 1) null pointer exception or 2) you're stepping on uninitialized stuff. In this particular case, it's the index 20 of a 20-long array with `scanf(" %c", &right_choices[20]);`

Comment: Your line `num_choices = num_choices - 1 + 'A';` is equivalent to a simple `num_choices+=64`, since `-1+'A'` equals 64. What exactly are you doing here?

Answer (score 1):

C is a 0-indexed language, change your loop to

```
for( k=0; k < sizeof right_choices; k++) {
    scanf(" %c", &right_choices[k]);
}
```

Comment: `k <= 19` was better before as `k < 20`. You've introduced another magic number, but `20` is the *same* magic number as used to define the array, so easier to maintain or convert to a single reference.

Comment: @Neil good idea! Edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Arrays in almost all languages work in the same way. when you create `foo[20]`, that means your array looks like `[0][1]...[18][19]`.

The element `right_choices[20]` doesn't exist, it should be `right_choices[k]`